# Combining ignore http line while searching for consecutive digits

Tags: regex

What I am accomplishing is searching each line for consecutive 8 digits.  I have that working.

This is the regular expression:

```
  ^.*(\b[0-9]{8}\b)$
```

**This is the test data:  It is picking up each consecutive numeric digits on each line.**

```
1. This is my account number 32145678
2. t 12345678
3. 43215678
4. 54321678
```

Now, what I am doing is ignoring any line with https or http in it.

```
(?is)^(?!http:|https:)$|^.*(\b[0-9]{8}\b)$
```

Below is the test data.  Lines 1,2,4,5,6,7 should match.  Line 3 should be ignored.

```
1. 87654321
2. 12345678
3. http://example.org/app=87654321
4. This is my account number 32145678
5. t 12345678
6. 43215678
7. 54321678
```

What is happening now is only line 7 is being match.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried `^(?!http:|https:)$|^.*(\b[0-9]{8}\b)$` the first part `^(?!http:|https:)$` will only match an empty string.

It means match any empty string asserting what is on the right is not `http:` or `https:`

You make use of an inline s [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) which will make the dot in the second part `^.*(\b[0-9]{8}\b)$` match a newline.

Having all those values after each other, the capturing group will capture the last 8 digits of all the values and that is why you see that only line 7 is being captured. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bd5bTN/1) having the multiline flag enabled)

---

You could update the pattern to

```
(?mi)^(?!https?:).*\b(\d{8})$
```

- `(?mi)` Inline modifiers for multiline and case insensitive
- `^` Start of line
- `(?!https?:)` Assert what is directly on the right is not http: or https:
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `\b(\d{8})` Word boundary, capture 8 digits in **group 1**
- `$` End of line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d3ciA3/1)

Note that you can omit the word boundary between `\b)$`

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is exactly what I needed and why!

Answer (score 0):

A couple points:

- Change the `i` flag to `m`. `i` means "single line," which essentially means "treat everything as a single line. With `i` flagged, a `.` will find new line characters. `m` is for `multiline`, which means that `^` and `$` equal the beginning or end of any line, respectively.
- Remove the `$` and the `|` from after the `(http:|https:)`. The `|` means "or" and you don't want an or in this case, you want to find a string of 8 numbers that are not preceded by http or https. Also, with the `$` in the regex pattern, you are stating that the http/https will be at the end of a string.

So you should end up with:

`(?im)^(?!http:|https:).*(\b[0-9]{8}\b)$`